# Can I have an SVG path end where it intersects another element?

Tags: svg

If I have an ellipse and a line, is there some way to make the line end where it hits the edge of the ellipse?  Eg:

```
<svg>
  <defs>
    <marker
      id="arrow"
      viewBox="0 0 10 5"
      refX="10"
      refY="2.5"
      markerUnits="strokeWidth"
      markerWidth="5"
      markerHeight="2.5"
      orient="auto"
    >
      <path
        d="M 0 0 L 10 2.5 L 0 5 z"
        fill="context-stroke"
        stroke="context-stroke"
      />
    </marker>
  </defs>

  <g transform="translate(50%, 50%)">
    <line x1="-200" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0" marker-end="url(#arrow)"/>
    <ellipse cx="0" cy="0" rx="100" ry="40" stroke="#000"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

The marker is covered up by the ellipse.  Is there a way to make the line end where it meets the ellipse so that the marker appears outside of the ellipse?

Obviously in this case it's easy to calculate where the line meets the ellipse and move the line end to there, but in general it's not, especially if the line is actually a more complex path.

Comment: In short, no — at least not that I'm aware of. You'll have to calculate it.

Comment: There is the ``svg.intersection.js`` library: https://amatiash.github.io/svg.intersections.js/demo.html

Comment: Or edit in a vector program like Illustrator or Inkscape: duplicate the arc, select the line and arc then union(?) the two and delete the portions of the copied arc. Note - test this on retina screens - you may get some hairline gaps. Solution - make sure fills and line overlap slightly.

Comment: @Ruskin the question didn't touch on this but the SVG is being generated on the client side at runtime (using d3-force).  Manual steps aren't going to work.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman thanks for the pointer!  That library is brilliant and does exactly what I'm after.  Feel free to write it up into an answer and I'll accept.